# Does the document in the db have to match the schema exactly in order to populate the queried doc?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My model is only querying the _id of the document. Does the document in the db have to match the schema exactly in order to populate the queried doc? For example. If my schema is {FirstName:String, LastName:String} and I insert {FirstName:'Rocky'} in the mongo term, would my Mongoose query only query the _id?

Schema: https://gist.github.com/fourq/5118f6237bf2fcc38a4b

Inserted Data: https://gist.github.com/fourq/d86d1b7b446f754efa17

What I get back when I query: https://gist.github.com/fourq/1fbbe6c8126b238a9b02

Answer (score 0):

It was my lack of understanding on how to query the items I needed. I resolved this.